# install wireless HP laserjet Pro M102w

Tags: printer, hp

I have a new install of Elem OS . Now want to add my HP laser jet pro M102w wireless printer .

When asked to select the printer from the list my printer did not appear. which driver will be compatible?  Is there some setting with the wireless connection that I should check?

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip

choose Ubuntu from the drop-down list and download recommended drivers (HPLIP).

Instructions are on the website I provided, however I cannot guarantee it will work.